# sample size Monte Carlo experiment

Tags: monte-carlo, convergence, bernoulli-distribution

I'm studying Monte Carlo analysis but I find very counter-intituive the computation of the minimum sample size in order to reach a certain level of precision. As stated in *Monte Carlo methods in Financial Engineering*, such sample size comes from the CLT and it can be computed according to

$$n = \frac{z^2_{\delta/2} \sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$$

My experiment is the classic Bernoulli variable, with $p$ probability of success.
Suppose my level of precision is $0.01$, then my $z_{0.01/2} = 2.57$.

I consider three cases.

$p=0.1\%$

$p=1\%$

$p=10\%$

With $\sigma^2 = p(1-p)$, I get

$n_{10\%} = 2.57^2 \cdot 0.1 \cdot 0.9 / 0.01^2 = 5944$

$n_{1\%} = 2.57^2 \cdot 0.01 \cdot 0.99 / 0.01^2 = 654$

$n_{0.1\%} = 2.57^2 \cdot 0.001 \cdot 0.999 / 0.01^2 =  66$

Intuitevely I would think the rarer the event, the greater the number of the simulations needed in order to approach the theoretical mean.
What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr: you're wrong, and your error is that you're mistaking *absolute error* and *relative error*.

Long response: the formula you reports gives the sample size needed to get a certain *absolute* estimation error. If the probability becomes smaller, it's obvious that you need *less* runs to get an estimate with the same absolute error, because intuitively your estimate will usually be close to zero, and thus to the quantity you're estimating. If I want to estimate a probability $p=0.01$ with an absolute error $\epsilon = 0.01$, i.e., a relative error of $100\%$, this means that 0 or 0.02 are acceptable estimates. Intuitively, this is much simpler than estimating a larger probability $p=0.5$ with the same absolute error $\epsilon = 0.01$, which in this case corresponds to a relative error of $2\%$.

Practical example: suppose $p=0.01$ is the probability of obtaining "heads" in a loaded coin, and I throw my coin just once. I will likely get "tails", since $p$ is so small. Now, my Monte Carlo estimate of $p$ is

$$\hat{p}_N=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N X_i}{N}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^1 0}{1} = 0$$

Is this acceptable, according to my *absolute error* criterion of $\epsilon = 0.01$? Obviously yes:

$$|\hat{p}_1-p|=|0-0.01|=0.01=\epsilon$$

Thus, as you can see, with just 1 throw of my coin, I got an acceptable (according to your criterion) estimate of $p$. Since the probability of getting "heads" in one throw is $0.01$, you can easily convince yourself that you will get an acceptable estimate on average $99$ times out of $100$, i.e., the confidence level (what you called precision) is $0.01$. On the other hand, note that the *relative error* is huge: in the best case, my one-throw estimate gives me a relative error

$$\frac{|\hat{p}_1-p|}{p}=\frac{0.01}{0.01}=1> 0.01=\epsilon$$

Consider instead the case of $p=0.5$: if you throw your coin only once, you can get an estimate of $0$ or $1$ with the same probability. This means that, on a single throw, your absolute error will be much larger than $0.01$ (it will always be $0.5$): you need more throws to get the desired absolute error.

You would have been right if you had considered the *relative* error: in that case, it's true that to get the same *relative* error when $p\to0$, you need much more throws than when $p$ is large. As a matter of fact, you can easily prove, following the same asymptotic approximation used to derive the formula you report, that the sample size needed to estimate the success probability of a Bernoulli RV with a relative estimation error $\epsilon$ and a confidence $\delta$ is

$$n=\frac{z^2_{\delta/2} \frac{(1-p)}{p}}{\epsilon^2}$$

I leave it as an exercise for you to prove that the paradox you observed before, has now disappeared.

However, note that in practice this formula is a very *bad* estimate of the sample size, because the CLT approximation for the sample mean of a sequence of Bernoulli RVs breaks down when $p\to 0$. Or, more precisely, the sample size needed in order for the normal approximation to be an accurate approximation of the distribution of $\hat{p}_N$, grows indefinitely when $p\to0$.

**UPDATE**: so, if the confidence interval for $\hat{p}_N$, based on the CLT, is so bad when $p\to 0$, what are better solutions? I include here some suggestions which I and the OP originally discussed in the comments, since comments should be temporary and only have the purpose to improve Q&A.

1. In the regime of large $n$ and small $p$, when the normal approximation to the binomial distribution becomes increasingly worse, the Poisson approximation becomes increasingly more accurate, so that could be a tool. See [here](https://klein.mit.edu/%7Ermd/650/binomconfints.pdf)
2. However, using another analytical approximation and then having to derive the corresponding CI by hand is surely educational, but hardly a good way of spending limited time if your goal is to quickly have an accurate estimate. Also, large $n$ and small $p$ or large $n$ and $p\approx 0.5$ are just two "boundary" regimes: what about other cases? Which CI should you use there? Of course, a lot of research has been devoted to the definition of CIs for binomial proportions which are more accurate and robust than the Wald (CLT-based) one. See [Brown et al., Interval Estimation for a Binomial Proportion, *Statistical Science*, Volume 16, Issue 2 (2001), 101-133](https://doi.org/10.1214/ss/1009213286) for the related theory and

   [Confidence interval for binomial data in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21719578)

   [Confidence interval for Bernoulli sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/confidence-interval-for-bernoulli-sampling)

   [Binomial confidence interval estimation - why is it not symmetric?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/binomial-confidence-interval-estimation-why-is-it-not-symmetric)

   to compute such intervals in R.
3. The original question, however, wasn't how to compute accurate & robust CIs for binomial proportions, or it would have been a duplicate. It was about computing the sample size needed for a certain *relative* or *absolute* accuracy $\epsilon$ in the estimation of $\hat{p}_N$. Thus, to get such an estimate directly without even having to invert the confidence interval, you can use [this R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/binomSamSize/index.html).

Comment: I got where I was mistaken, thanks...about your last remark, could I use the Poisson approximation in order to get better results?

Comment: Really thanks for the links. I've also found an R module which directly computes the correspondent sample size for many of the alternative estimators, it's called "binomSamSize". 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/binomSamSize/index.html

(hope it'll be useful also for someone else)